# Difference between the filter options in playwright

Tags: c#, playwright

Playwright document says for filter options we can use these four to match the text. They seem to be same.I would like to know the diference

https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/api/class-locator#locator-filter

**HasNotText|HasNotTextRegex** string?|Regex? (optional)
Matches elements that do not contain specified text somewhere inside, possibly in a child or a descendant element. When passed a string, matching is case-insensitive and searches for a substring.

**HasText|HasTextRegex** string?|Regex? (optional)

Matches elements containing specified text somewhere inside, possibly in a child or a descendant element. When passed a string, matching is case-insensitive and searches for a substring. For example, "Playwright" matches Playwright.

**HasTextString|HasNotTextString** string?|Regex? (optional)

Matches elements containing specified text somewhere inside, possibly in a child or a descendant element. When passed a string, matching is case-insensitive and searches for a substring. For example, "Playwright" matches Playwright.

Comment: I think that's a bug. I'll report that

Answer (score 0):

HasNotText matches the opposite of HasText.

Given these three html anchors:

```html
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">Stackoverflow</a>
<a href="https://www.playwright.dev">Playwright</a>
<a href="https://www.nodejs.org/">Node</a>
```

```js
.Filter(new() { HasText = "Stackoverflow" })
// Returns locator of the Stackoverflow link

.Filter(new() { HasNotText = "Stackoverflow" })
// Returns locator of both Playwright AND Node anchors since it matches 
// all links that are NOT "Stackoverflow"
```

Comment: sorry for not being clear...I wanted to know the difference between HasText, HasTextString

Comment: @mohammedazaharuddin I am confused. When clicking the link you are referring to, there is no method `HasTextString`, only `HasText` which accepts either string or regex as argument.